# Bond BLE device previously bonded with classic bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an Android application which connects to an external device via bluetooth. This external device has 2 ways to work: using classic bluetooth or BLE. Only one of them can be selected.

After connecting and bonding to the device using any bluetooth version, I have to enable the notifications in a X descriptor. That's the main goal.

Suppose that I have previously bonded the device using the classic bluetooth.
After that, if I change the device's protocol from classic blueetoth to BLE and I try connecting, bonding and enabling the notifications, this last step is not changing anything.

I think that Android knows that the device was previously bonded using classic bluetooth so that step is not being executed. For that reason, the "writeDescriptor" function is not changing anything because the device needs to be bonded in order to execute that task. However, I'm getting GATT_SUCCESS status code instead of GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMITTED as I expected.

So is it possible to force the bonding process? I used Nordic's nRF Connect and after enabling CCCDs, the bonding process starts, which is what I need.

**EDIT: I tried with an Android 7.0 device and it works, so it seems that the problem is related with the Android version.**

Comment: I've realized that Android automatically unbonds a device if it was previously bonded using BLE and if it changes to bluetooth classic afterwards. It doesn't happen the other way around.